# Java - Applet doesn't work on Firefox when usign ForkJoinPool (while in Eclipse works)

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, applet

when I run the following code on Eclipse (Luna, java vers=8), the code runs and pops-up the two errors messages. On the other hand, when I embed the code in a html page the code shows only the first error message. It seems that calling the ForkJoinPool class crushes the applet on firefox.
Do you know why? Here is the code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ProvaVera extends JApplet
{
    public void start() 
    {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() 
            {
                MainPanel panel = new MainPanel();      
                // Add Swing components to content pane
                Container c = getContentPane();
                c.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            }
        });

    }

}
class MainPanel extends JPanel
{

    public MainPanel()
    {
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("label1");
        this.add(label1);
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("button1");
        this.add(btn1);

        btn1.addActionListener  (
                new ActionListener() 
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        metodo();
                    }
                }

                );
    }



    public void metodo()
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "test1", "Dialog", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "test2", "Dialog", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have enabled the Java console from the java control panel.
And the error was:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread")

So I went to my java.policy file located in java.home/lib/security/ and I wrote the following

```
grant codeBase "url or file where the applet is" {
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThread";
};
```

And now the applet is working.

Again, thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting a security exception because `ForkJoinPool` requires the 'modifyThread' runtime permission.

When you run in Eclipse there is no security manager installed so you don't get security exceptions. When you run in a browser there is a strict security manager.